# REST HTTP codes for business logic errors

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I'm trying to understand the principles of building REST HTTP API's, and I'm having troubles with HTTP response codes. I've read [this article](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) and I still cannot understand which code the REST API should output if the request cannot be successfully completed due to some restrictions enforced by complex business logic.

For example, an online shop API is exposing a method for adding an item into the cart, and the shop manager decided to enforce a few rules regarding this:

- products of categories A and B cannot be added to the same cart
- the total discount amount for all products in the cart cannot exceed $10
- products of category A cannot be added to the cart on Mondays

If any of these rules would be violated after adding a new item to the cart, I can send JSON responses like `{ "Result": "Failed", "Reason": "TotalDiscountCannotExceed10Dollars"}`, etc, but what kind of HTTP status code sould I send along with the response?

Comment: Something like `400 Bad Request` would work - the data/conditions requested by the user cannot be fulfilled by the app. It's worth taking a look at how other APIs do this - many simply return a normal HTTP response code, but put any errors in the message. Take a look at [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)/Dropbox/etc API docs and see what they do. [Twitter use many](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes), including `420 Enhance Your Calm`.

Comment: I'd go with [`409 Conflict`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) as on adding a second produrct to your cart you modify the current state of the cart and already have some previous state in it. The user might resolve the issue by removing one of the unique products or reduce the number of items so that the total amount does not exceed $10. You should [read through](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5) the available error codes and their meaning ...

Answer (score 3):

it Could be much better if you add in-house json error response status code of these kind of failure which is not related to HTTP. as here
{ "Result": "Failed", "Reason": "TotalDiscountCannotExceed10Dollars"} 
response is success from server (http -200 OK), but error in json response(failed).

so for these error you must have some customised json Error response. and for more flexible you can categorise these error by self understanding..

Comment: This makes only sense if this is enforced by a custom media type as otherwise a client will never know what a certain field inside a response code relates to and how the client should behave in such a case

Comment: i don't think client will react here if you notify it by http also. here error have to throw in data not in return code. only case if you to tight up the data with specify http code then you need changes here.  for that case you can use 5xx as error send from server services.

Comment: I would use 422. Unprocessable entity. Returning 200 might be confusing...